# Prove that if $x =\frac{p}{q} \in (0, 1], q > 1$, then the period $P$ of repeating digits of $x$ is in fact less than or equal to $q − 1$.

Tags: real-numbers

Prove that if $x =\frac{p}{q}
\in (0, 1]$ is a rational number, $q > 1$, then the period $P$ of repeating digits in the decimal
representation of $x$ is in fact less than or equal to $q − 1$.

Comment: I have been, I don't see how I can link the number of repeating digits to the denominator at all. All I can see is that p must be less than q which doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Do you know how to do long division? Can you use it to compute decimal expansions, e.g. of 1/7 or 1/13, without using a calculator?

Comment: yes I do know how to do long division

Comment: You should try some examples, like computing 1/3, 1/7, 1/9, 1/11, 1/13...

Answer (score 1):

If you have any knowledge of modular arithmetic, then you can do it. But it is important that you enjoy proving it yourself.

**Hint 1**: (follows from the Division algorithm) when $a,b \in \mathbb N,$ dividing $a$ by $b$ always gives a remainder $r$ such that $r \in \{0,1,...,(b-1)\}.$ This set is infact known as the residue system of $b$.

**Hint2**: [The Pigeon Hole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) (which is pretty much common sense).

Please let me know whether you could prove it yourself.

Comment: I've gotten as far writing down that the remainder x is either has finite decimals or recurring decimals